# XCode auto-scroll when pressing Command after a text selection

Tags: xcode, scroll, command

Xcode is scrolling my window when I press Command sometime, which makes my copy/paste tricky. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when:

- you use your 3 fingers to drag and do a selection
- then release your fingers in the small grey border ("sensible area" in capture)

[image: sensible area]

It's just a bug. Just click to drag.